# Does cockroachdb support mTLS?

Tags: authentication, ssl, cockroachdb, mtls

I need CockroachDB to work securely in my particular cloud setup. Specifically, I need it to perform mutual TLS authentication both when serving SQL and when making outgoing requests via changefeeds, and I need it to do so using a specific root certificate. I see CockroachDB has a lot of settings to do with authentication, but can it support bidirectional mTLS?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. mTLS just means "client and server both authenticate using TLS," and CockroachDB supports TLS as both a [server](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/authentication.html) and [client](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/v22.2/changefeed-sinks#webhook-sink), including the ability to configure the ca_cert, client_cert, and client_key. One caveat is that support varies for different kinds of changefeed sinks. Configuring client authentication to a Confluent Schema Registry will be supported in versions 22.2.4 and up.